# Two automations using the same file drop

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio

Has anyone been successful in triggering two automations from one file drop? I'm testing it and it seems to be corrupting something on the back end. As soon as I try to create a second automation using the same file drop, things start failing. I'm wondering if anyone has gotten this to work, and if so, how?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried it in the past and faced the same issue. 
The problem is that you have contention on the file i.e. two processes trying to use the same file, thereby the first process has locked the file, the second process fails.

You could combine your automation into one - so you have 1 automation with one file trigger.

Or you could configure one automation with the file trigger, and then use an SSJS script in the first automation to trigger the 2nd automation once the first automation is complete.

Comment: That makes sense (your first paragraph) and support told me the same thing. I'd rather not combine them because I like to keep series separate. I came up with a workaround to just run the other automation an hour after the first file drops, since we know when it drops. Great option in par 3 though, will keep it in mind for future work